# Validacion de celdas en dos archivos excel con diferentes paginas

Tags: excel, algoritmos, formulas

Estoy validando unos nombres y me dan primero apellido coma nombre es decir que tengo que reversarlo. Por ejemplo Herrera, Eduardo Herrera y tambien lo reverso con esta formula `NOMPROPIO(EXTRAE(C4&" "&C4,ENCONTRAR(",",C4)+2,LARGO(C4)-1))`. Me dan otro row o celda a identificar pero siempre trae unas siglas que son las cuatro primeras que elimino por defecto, justamente uso esta sentencia para eliminar las primeras letras `REEMPLAZAR(B4,1,4,""),Hoja5!B2)` . El detalle es que estoy validando en un excel en paginas diferentes por ahora. Justamente mi algoritmo o sentencia en excel esta escrita de la siguiente forma `SI(if(IGUAL(REEMPLAZAR(B4,1,4,""),Hoja5!B2),IGUAL(NOMPROPIO(EXTRAE(C4&" "&C4,ENCONTRAR(",",C4)+2,LARGO(C4)-1)),Hoja5!A2)))` .

En la evaluacion, me muestra esto todo esta bien verdadero y verdadero, deberia marcarme true mas no nombre o la palabra si.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes `if` en tu segunda fórmula si estás formulando en español?